# How can I write strings into a file using a parent and two child processes?

Tags: c, unix, process, fork

I'm trying to solve this problem but I cannot.

Here is a short description:

> We have a parent with two child processes (child_a, child_b) and N strings.
>
> Current data: data[i] (0...N)
>
> 1. Parent starts and waiting for signal from child_b. Child_a is waiting.
> 2. Child_b sends a signal to parent and waiting for data.
> 3. Parent write data[i] into pipe and waiting
> 4. Child_b reads data[i] from pipe and printf(). Then waiting for Child_a
> 5. Child_a generates a random number (between 1-5) and write into pipe.
> 6. Child_b reads rand from pipe and sends to Parent.
> 7. Parent write "data[i] - rand" into a file.
> 8. And start from the begining with next data...

Here is my code:

```
FILE *fp2;
fp2 = fopen("bill.dat" , "a");

pid_t child_a, child_b;
int pipefd_a[2], pipefd_b[2];
char msg[100];
char sleep_time[10];

int stat;

signal(SIGUSR1, handler);
signal(SIGUSR2, handler);

if(pipe(pipefd_a) == -1 || pipe(pipefd_b) == -1){
    perror("Error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int i;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){

    child_a = fork();

    if(child_a < 0){
        perror("Error\n");
    }

    if(child_a == 0){
        sleep(1);
        printf("Child_a-----\n");
        srand(time(NULL));
        int r = rand()%5+1;
        char rand[2];
        sprintf(rand, "%d", r);
        printf("Child_a rand: %s\n", rand);
        write(pipefd_b[1], rand, strlen(rand)+1);
        printf("Child_a end-----\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        child_b = fork();

        if(child_b == 0){
            printf("Child_b sends a signal to parent\n");
            kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
            close(pipefd_a[1]);
            read(pipefd_a[0], msg, sizeof(msg));
            close(pipefd_a[0]);
            printf("Child_b reads from pipe (from parent): %s\n", msg);
            kill(child_a, SIGUSR2);
            sleep(2);
            read(pipefd_b[0], sleep_time, 10);
            printf("Child_b reads from pipe (from child_a): %s\n", sleep_time);
            fflush(NULL);
            write(pipefd_b[1], sleep_time, sizeof(sleep_time));
            close(pipefd_b[1]);
            printf("Child_b end-----\n");
            exit(0);

        }
        printf("============== %d ============== \n", i);
        printf("Parent waiting for signal...\n");
        pause();
        printf("Signal received\n");
        printf("Parent write into pipe\n");
        close(pipefd_a[0]);
        write(pipefd_a[1], data[i].address, 100);
        kill(child_b, SIGUSR2);
        waitpid(child_b, &stat, 0);
        read(pipefd_b[0], msg, sizeof(msg));
        fprintf(fp2, "%s - %s\n", data[i].address, msg);
        printf("Parent writes into file: %s\n", msg);
    }

}
fclose(fp2);
```

and my output (n = 2):

- data1 - 1
- data1 - 1
- data1 - 1
- data2 - 3

There are always 2^n lines in the file.
The assignment requires two child processes to achieve this and I suspect that the problem is with the "fork()" within the loop, but don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You keep overwriting the pid for the children each lap of the loop, shouldn't `child_a` and `child_b` be arrays? Also, is there an actual reason why you need multiple processes and IPC, instead of using multi-threading?

Comment: The task description suggest that you should only fork before the loop and child_a and child_b should persist until the data list is exhausted.

Comment: Dear Lundin, thank you for your comment. The assignment requires this approach (multiple processes and IPC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you put your process creation in for loop.
That is why you get 2n lines. If you want to read some data form file N times you don't make N processes.

Second thing you need 3 pipes for your work. Pipe is unidirectional meaning one process can only write into pipe and the other can only read from it. One end is for writing and the other end is for reading, so you must close unused descriptors!

- first pipe is used when parent writes data[i] into pipe and child_b reads
- second pipe is used when child_a  writes a random number into pipe and child_b reads
- third pipe is used when child_b writes into pipe and parent performs reading

If you could write the whole program it would be easier form me to understand it and to help you.
This is skeleton how i would try to make this work

```
int pipe_parent_to_childB[2], pipe_childB_to_parent[2], pipe_childA_to_childB;

if(pipe(pipe_parent_to_childB) == -1 || pipe(pipe_childB_to_parent) == -1 ||pipe(pipe_childA_to_childB) == -1)
{
            perror("Error\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

//close read end because parent will write to pipe
close(pipe_parent_to_childB[0]);

switch(fork()) //create child b
{
    case -1:
        //error
    case 0:
        //now you are in child_b
        close(pipe_parent_to_childB[1]);
        close(pipe_childA_to_childB[1]);

        //perform some action


    default:
        break;
        }
}
switch(fork()) //crete child a
{
     case -1:
                //error
     case 0:
                //now you are in child_a
                close(pipe_childA_to_childB[0]);
                //perform some action

     default:
         break;


}

//here you are in parent process again. Send signals, wait for signals and write to pipe here
//from parent you send some data through pipe to process child_b N times
//after this you close write end of the pipe descriptor.
```

Comment: Thank you, you have helped me so much! Now i fully understand what's happening in my code.

Comment: Glad i could help :)